# Подскажите фреймворки/библиотеки для работы с backend на Golang

Tags: golang, mvc, backend

Сейчас работаю на Django, и хотелось бы узнать, есть ли аналог на Golang? Самое главное при выборе - MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужен аналог Django, то выбирайте Beego. Правда там есть куча своих нюансов. Об этом можете почитать в статье:
https://habr.com/ru/post/444022/

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Сначала подумал, что ответ вида "если вам нужно как Django, то и используйте Django". Ну вообще это самый логичный вариант был бы.